# Is it possible to format text in a scroll view in a storyboard which is longer than one screen?

Tags: ios

I have a requirement to implement a view controller containing a scrolling screen of text formatted like

```
HEADER 1 (red, larger text)
Body content 1 extending over a few lines (black, smaller text)

HEADER 2 (red, larger text)
Body content 2 extending over a few lines (black, smaller text)

HEADER 3 (red, larger text)
Body content 3 extending over a few lines (black, smaller text)
```

And so on extending for about 9 sections.

If I implement this in a scroll view, then within the storyboard its only possible to layout and format one screen's worth of content (the first 3 or 4 header/body pairs).

Is it possible to somehow format all the content in the scroll view in the storyboard? If not is there another way to implement this that is easy to visually format the content?

Comment: why not using `UITableView` instead?

Comment: Use a UITableView where each cell contains a heading and a body label

Comment: It is probably better to just format all your text as a single attributed string and put it in a `UITextView` that scrolls, or to format it as HTML and put it in a `WebView`.